# Plugging in $\hat{\Sigma}$ For $\Sigma$ In Multivariate Gaussian Formula

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, substitution

I'd like to plug-in the estimate of $\Sigma$ in a likelihood calculation,

$$
p(\{x\}) =
\prod _{i=1}^{n} \frac{1}{C}
\exp \bigg[-\frac{ 1}{2}(x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu) \bigg]
$$

where $C = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{k/2} \det(\Sigma)^{1/2}}$. The maximum likelihood estimate is, as we know,

$$ \hat{\Sigma} = \frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=1}^{n} (x_k-\hat{\mu}) (x_k-\hat{\mu})^T $$

And since

$$ p(\{x\}) =
\frac{1}{C^n}
\exp \bigg[\sum _{i=1}^{n} -\frac{ 1}{2}(x_i-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x_i-\mu) \bigg]
$$

Could I plug-in the estimate (for both $\mu$ and $\Sigma$) like this?

$$
= \frac{1}{C^n} \exp \bigg[\sum _{i=1}^{n} 
-\frac{ 1}{2n}(x_i-\hat{\mu})^T 
\bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=1}^{n} (x_k-\hat{\mu}) (x_k-\hat{\mu})^T \bigg]^{-1}
(x_i-\hat{\mu}) \bigg]
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{C^n} \exp \bigg[\sum _{i=1}^{n} 
-\frac{ 1}{2} 
\bigg[
\frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\hat{\mu})^{-T} (x_k-\hat{\mu}) (x_k-\hat{\mu})^T (x_i-\hat{\mu})^{-1}
\bigg]^{-1}
 \bigg]
$$

$$
= \frac{1}{C^n} \exp \bigg[\sum _{i=1}^{n} 
-\frac{ 1}{2}  \bigg[ \frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=1}^{n} 1 \bigg]^{-1} \bigg]
$$

$$ = \frac{1}{C^n} \exp \bigg[\sum _{i=1}^{n} 
-\frac{ 1}{2}  \bigg[ \frac{1}{n} n \bigg]^{-1} \bigg]
 $$

$$ = \frac{1}{C^n} \exp \bigg[\sum _{i=1}^{n} 
-\frac{ 1}{2}   \bigg]
 $$

$$
= \frac{1}{C^n} \exp \bigg[-\frac{n}{2} \bigg]
$$

Thanks,

Comment: If $\Sigma$ is p.d., then $\hat\Sigma$ is p.d. and hence invertible with probability 1. However you did some errors in the plug in. The constant $C$ is not free of $\Sigma$. So there should be a $\hat{C}$ I suppose. And if you assume $\Sigma$ is a $p\times p$ matrix. You should arrive at $\exp(-np/2)$ somewhere in the expression.

Comment: I did some changes, could you take a look again? I now have $\exp(-n/2)$ as the final expression.

Comment: $$
 \frac{1}{C^n} \exp \bigg[\sum _{i=1}^{n} 
-\frac{ 1}{2} 
\bigg[
\frac{1}{n} \sum _{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\hat{\mu})^{-T} (x_k-\hat{\mu}) (x_k-\hat{\mu})^T (x_i-\hat{\mu})^{-1}
\bigg]^{-1}
 \bigg]
$$
the vectors are not invertible

Comment: On $C$ I'd plug in $\hat{\Sigma}$ there too, for my purposes this is fine.

Comment: Vectors are not invertible. Right. My mistake. So.. isn't there any way to do this plug-in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am addressing only the issue of how to rewrite the likelihood with plug in estimates.

Let $z_i=x_i-\hat{\mu}$. We assume $z_i$ are $p\times 1$ vectors. At some point we need to evaluate
$$\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^T\left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}z_i$$
We assume the invertibility of the above matrix. We use the trace operator. It has some remarkable properties, like $\operatorname{tr}(A+B)=\operatorname{tr}(A)+\operatorname{tr}(B)$ and $\operatorname{tr}(AB)=\operatorname{tr}(BA)$. Note that
$$\begin{aligned} \sum_{i=1}^n z_i^T\left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}z_i & = \operatorname{tr}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^T\left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}z_i\right] \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{tr}\left[ z_i^T\left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}z_i\right] \\ & = \sum_{i=1}^n\operatorname{tr}\left[ \left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}z_iz_i^T\right] \\ & =
\operatorname{tr}\left[ \left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^nz_iz_i^T\right] = \operatorname{tr}(I_p)=p \end{aligned}$$

Hence 
$$\begin{aligned}\exp\left[-\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^T\left(\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}z_i\right] & = \exp\left[-\frac{n}2\sum_{i=1}^n z_i^T\left(\sum_{k=1}^n z_kz_k^T\right)^{-1}z_i\right]=\exp(-np/2)\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Crazy awesome! Thanks.